# Specific Section and Page Numbering InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, section-marker

I am new to InDesign and I am trying to get my head around how to do something with the page numbering.

I want to do this:

Have at the top of the page Sec 01.1 (the .1 signifies the page number of inside the current section) as well as a page number 01 at the bottom of the page but its the absolute page number of the entire document. Is it possible to do this?

I also need (or rather want) the section to be the format '01.1' and the page number to be 01. But seems I can only have one or the other, unless I add the 0 manually for the first 9 pages.